# Does Magic Trackpad 2 work with Mac without Bluetooth?

Tags: mac, bluetooth, magic-trackpad

A simple question for owners of Magic Trackpad - Is it possible to connect it through cable, to a computer that doesn't have Bluetooth?

Or does the cable work just for charging, and the communication is Bluetooth-only?

EDIT: The [document](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/connect-an-apple-wireless-accessory-mchlp2656/mac) linked in Nimesh Neema's answer might mean either `connect through lighting cable to use it wired`, or `connect it through cable to pair Bluetooth automatically` (similar to how you plug Pencil into iPad to pair them).

So there seem to be three posssibilities:

1. cable is only for charging
2. cable serves for charging and pairing (BT is still needed for use)
3. cable actually serves for communication (BT is not necessary)

And it's either 2 or 3.

Comment: Awesome question, I will upvote it, as this is the question I was asking myself for a long time... 
 
The main motivations for this are, for example, what if I need to do a startup action, where, I guess, BT is not connected yet? Or what if I want to install some other OS (as some Linux distro) in my old MacOS?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Does Magic Trackpad 2 works with Mac without Bluetooth?

Yes.

> Is it possible to connect it through the USB to Lightning cable, to a computer that doesn't have Bluetooth?

Yes.

> Or does the cable work just for charging, and the communication is Bluetooth-only?

The communication can be done over cable, just like how a wired keyboard or a Trackpad would work.

This Apple Support document sheds more light:

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchlp2656/mac

> #### Connect a Magic Keyboard, Magic Mouse 2 or Magic Trackpad 2 with your Mac
>
> When you connect your keyboard, mouse or trackpad to your Mac, it automatically connects with the Mac using Bluetooth.
>
> - Connect one end of a Lightning to USB Cable to your Magic Keyboard, Magic Mouse 2 or Magic Trackpad 2 and the other end to the USB port on your Mac. Depending on your Mac, you may need an adapter, which is available from an Apple Store or on apple.com.
>
> *You can use your Magic Keyboard or Magic Trackpad 2 while it’s connected to your Mac. You can’t use your Magic Mouse 2 while it’s connected.*

A Magic Mouse can't be used as the Lighting port is located at the bottom of the mouse making it impractical to use it with the cable connected.

<sub>Quoted text added for context. Emphasis on the italicised part.</sub>

Comment: I am reading the linked document (thank you), but to me, the `When you connect your keyboard, mouse, or trackpad to your Mac, it automatically connects with the Mac using Bluetooth.` seems to mean `connect it through cable to pair Bluetooth automatically`, similar to how you plug Pencil into iPad to pair them - but that still might not mean that it will work without Bluetooth.

Comment: @TomášKafka Read it as this "also" does the pairing. If you do turn off Bluetooth on your Mac, the Trackpad can function as normal wired Trackpad.

Comment: Thanks! This `If you do turn off Bluetooth on your Mac, the Trackpad can function as normal wired Trackpad` is what I wanted to know - so it should work on non-bluetooth desktop :).

Comment: @TomášKafka I am glad it helped.

Comment: The answer to the question I had for a long time. Awesome, thanks, Nimesh!

Comment: Anyone know if the same is true of the wireless keyboards?

Comment: @opearmain The answer mentions both Magic Keyboard or Magic Trackpad 2 work while connected to Mac via Lightning cable.

Comment: @NimeshNeema right you are, thank you!

Comment: @NimeshNeema Any idea about the newer ('3', except they seem to have dropped numbering) trackpads? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458673/does-the-latest-magic-trackpad-3-but-not-mmmp3z-a-still-work-over-usb-with