# Does the latest Magic Trackpad ('3' but not, MMMP3Z/A) still work over USB, without bluetooth?

Tags: usb, bluetooth, magic-trackpad

I want to use a Magic Trackpad with a KVM. I can only find documentation about it working over USB when plugged in for the older models - does this still work with MMMP3Z/A, or is it now Bluetooth only?

Comment: I’ve never had much luck with Apple input devices on KVMs.  Granted, these were high end HP or Avocent models, but we never found them reliable in this type of switching environment.